# Парсинг не работает на второй странице

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

На сайте данные приведены в виде карточек (при наведении на них - увеличиваются [data-animation="zooming"]).
Парсинг с помощью requests и BeautifulSoup работает на первой странице, на второй для ссылок a href Python выбивает ошибку:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
и сохраняет csv с результатами только первой страницы, но второй и следующих нет. Использование fake_useragent и session = HTMLSession() не решает проблему. Где на view-source находятся данные для payload = { "jsonQuery":{ }}? Или какой наилучший способ все же собрать данные в таблицу - Node.js и Puppeteer?

Сайт - https://armacad.info/summer-schools?page=5&order=latest

Код:

```
import csv
import re
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

ua = UserAgent()

category = 'summer-schools'
last_page = 4

filename = f'armacad4-{category}-all.csv'
outfile = open(filename,'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['title', 'link'])

sleep(randint(5,10))

pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    URL = f'https://armacad.info/{category}?page={page}&order=latest'
    html = session.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent':ua.random})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
    jobs_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile(r'col-md-4')})
    
    sleep(randint(5,10))
    
    print ('Обрабатывается страница: %s' %(page))
    
    for card in jobs_list:
        title = card.find('span', class_='h4').text if card.find('span', class_='h4') is not None else '' 
        link = card.find('a').attrs['href'] if card.find('a').attrs['href'] is not None else ''
        
        
        writer.writerow([title, link])


outfile.close()
print ('Сбор завершен')
```

Comment: a можете добавить код? И ссылочку на сайт. Будет проще понять что у вас не так.

Comment: @Sergei Malanin вопрос отредактирован

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного отрефакторил. У меня заработало.

```py
import csv
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

ua = UserAgent()

category = 'summer-schools'
last_page = 4

filename = f'armacad4-{category}-all.csv'
outfile = open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['title', 'link'])

pages = list(range(1, int(last_page) + 1))
for page in pages:
    URL = f'https://armacad.info/{category}?page={page}&order=latest'
    html = session.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': ua.random})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
    jobs_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-md-4'})
    sleep_n = randint(2, 6)
    print(f"sleep for {sleep_n}")
    sleep(sleep_n)

    print('Обрабатывается страница: %s' % page)

    for card in jobs_list:
        print("parsing card")
        title = ''
        link = ''
        if card.find('span', class_='h4') is not None:
            title = card.find('span', class_='h4').text
        print(f"{title=}")
        if card.find('a') is not None:
            link = card.find('a').attrs['href']
        print(f"{link=}")
        writer.writerow([title, link])
        print("data written\n", "*"*20)

outfile.close()
print('Сбор завершен')
```

проблема была вот здесь

```py
link = card.find('a').attrs['href'] if card.find('a').attrs['href'] is not None else ''
```

`if card.find('a').attrs['href'] is not None` -> `if card.find('a') is not None`
P.S. Писать длинные выражения в одну строку плохо для чтения.
Код пишется один раз, читается 10.
Так же есть максимальный размер строки который удобно читать.
Обычно это 80, 100, 120. Обычно комманда договаривается об этом.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что нашли ошибку! Начинаю изучать парсинг и программирование, этот код - только для себя. Теперь вижу, что необходима была большая разбивка по шагам для дальнейшей отладки.